# Scheduling an event every day at a given time

Tags: mysql, event

I want my event to run everyday at 00:20. I am confused in scheduling of the time. Should I be using the first option or the second one?

**Option 1**

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2014-04-30 00:20:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO
    # My query
```

**Option 2**

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
  ON SCHEDULE
    AT ('2014-04-30 00:20:00'+ INTERVAL 1 DAY) ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO
    # My query
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the first one if you want to execute your event everyday.

The second syntax will execute once.

**Option 1**: Execute the event **every night at 00:20**

**Option 2**: Execute the event **once the 2014-05-01 at 00:20**

Max.

Comment: Just wondering: what does `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE` mean?

Comment: @KolobCanyon ON COMPLETION PRESERVE to make it a repeatable event so you don't have to create it again.